# How to simulate slow network connection?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

We are using **Jest / Enzyme** for our **React** integration **tests**. We have a component that shows a spinner whilst it is waiting for an iframe to load. When this page loads in a real-world browser environment, the spinner visibly shows. However, in the **test**, the spinner does not show because the iframe contents are **mocked** and they appear so quickly that the spinner does not have time to show. Is there a way to throttle the environment, such that we can see the correct behaviour depending on different real-world network speeds?

Comment: do you run `jest` directly or by platform like `puppeter`? how exactly do you "mock iframe content"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bit complex for a unit test with `jest` scenario. If your React component appears in two different states - loading with the spinner (state 1) and loaded with your content rendered (state 2) - then I'd set up your unit tests to test both of those states individually and to not worry about simulating network speeds / transitions from one state to another.

However if you really do want to simulate something like this then you do have an option.

Suppose you have a property `isLoaded` in your component which, when `false` means that your loading state is rendered. You can do something along the lines of rendering your component in the loading state to begin with (ie. set that `isLoaded` property to `false` or whatever your subsequent property is in your component) and do your **loading state** tests.

Then once you've done those, you can do something like the following:

```
wrapper.setProps({ isLoaded: true });
wrapper.update();
```

This will update your property and force a re-render, after which you should be able to do your **loaded state** tests.

I'd still recommend that you keep both sets of tests as individual as possible between the two states but this is a potential option for you if you wish to still work with transitioning from one state to another sequentially.

Unit tests are meant to be fast and concentrate on the behaviour of your code and components: not simulating real world network issues or waiting around for events to occur. Once your loading state is tested individually and your loaded state also tested individually, you've proven that both states work as expected when called upon.

From a unit testing perspective that's all you need.